# What ring is this? Related to Beal's conjecture

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer.  Let $R = (\Bbb{R}, \oplus, \cdot)$ be the ring defined as:

(1) $a \oplus b = (\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b})^n$, where $+$ on the RHS is usual, 
(2) $ab$ is usual multiplication in $\Bbb{R}$.

Clearly $R$ is a group under $\oplus$ since $- \sqrt[n]{a} = \sqrt[n]{-a}$.

Also, multiplication distributes: $c(a \oplus b) = c(\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b})^n = (\sqrt[n]{c}(\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b}))^n = ca \oplus cb$.

It's actually a field.

Comment: I will MO this if no one has an answer!!!

Comment: You should use $\oplus$ to distinguish the operation from the usual $+$. (Notice in (1) you use the "+" symbol in two contradictory ways.) All you've basically done is relabel the elements of $\Bbb R$. Relabeling the elements of a concrete algebraic structure according to some bijection is called [transport of structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Comment: I haven't re-labeled the elements.  I've used the same name and created a different operation.

Comment: And you get the same exact structure as $\Bbb R$ to begin with, only with the elements labelled differently.

Comment: Please don't threaten to post questions to MO if you don't get an answer within 20 minutes...

Comment: Posting to MO isn't in your interest anyway: since the question is inappropriate there, they would close it and/or kick it here, where it would be closed as a duplicate, and then people might remember you for it :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map $\mathbb{R}\to R$, $x\mapsto x^n$ is an isomorphism of rings.

Comment: $\phi(a + b) = (a + b)^n \neq (\sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{b})^n$

Comment: Let's write $\oplus$ for the addition on $R$. We have $\phi(a+b)=(a+b)^n=(\sqrt[n]{a^n}+\sqrt[n]{b^n})^n=a^n\oplus b^n=\phi(a)\oplus\phi(b)$

Comment: If the downvote was made because someone believed this answer was in error, then the downvoter is the one in error.