# Do I have this right? Are these conclusions valid in this isomorphic view of $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, proof-verification

Let $F = (\Bbb{R}, \oplus_d, \cdot)$ be the field with usual $\cdot$, and $\oplus_d$ is defined as $a \oplus b = (\sqrt[d]{a} + \sqrt[d]{b})^d$.  This field is isomorphic to usual $\Bbb{R}$ structure by $f: \Bbb{R} \to F, \ x \mapsto x^d$, $d$ an odd prime.

Since there are no positive integer solutions to $x^n + y^n - z^n = 0$, for $n \gt 2$, then for $d$ odd prime we have that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution if and only if $f(x^n + y^n -z^n) = 0 = x^{dn} \oplus y^{dn} \oplus -z^{dn}$, i.e. iff it's also a solution to that equation in $F$.  Then in summary, for all $n \gt 2$ and odd primes $d$,  $x^{dn} \oplus y^{dn} \oplus - z^{dn} = 0$ has no solution.

[**It is indeed a field.**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567689/what-ring-is-this-related-to-beals-conjecture)

Further, we have that $g: F \to F \ , x \mapsto x^d$, is a ring homomorphism.  Then we have that there are no solutions to $x^{d^k n} \oplus y^{d^k n} \oplus -z^{d^k n} = 0$ for all $k \geq 1$.

I just want to verify if this is all true and if you notice any interesting properties, please mention.  Thanks.

Consider the Beal equation $x^a + y^b - z^c = 0$.  Let $a,b,c$ be odd primes.  $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to it iff $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x^{d^k a} \oplus y^{d^k b} \oplus -z^{d^k c} = 0. \ $  So then using the inverse isomorphism $x \mapsto \sqrt[d]{x}, \ F \to \Bbb{R}$.  We have that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to the Beal equation iff it's a solution to $(x^{d^{k-1}a} + y^{d^{k-1}b} - z^{d^{k-1}c})^d = 0$ and since we're in an integral domain we can take the inside of that exponential equal to $0$.

Is *that* true?  Thank you!

**Edit**
So we have that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to the Beal equation iff it's a solution to

$$x^{d^k a} + y^{d^k b} - z^{d^k c} = 0$$

for $k \geq 0$.  But that's infinitely many solutions to FLT which is impossible.

That proves the Beal conjecture, but probably not! Where is my error?

According to Bruno Joyal in an answer down below.  $x \mapsto x^d$ is not an automorphism of $F$.  Indeed it is:

Clearly since it's the $d$th root function for odd $d$ it's a multiplicative bijection of the set $\Bbb{R}$ onto itself.  That's easy enough to show though: It has an inverse given by $x \mapsto \sqrt[d]{x}$.  So it's a bijection.  It's a homomorphism too: clearly it's multiplicative.  So let $x, y \in F$, then $(x \oplus y)^d = (\sqrt[d]{x} + \sqrt[d]{y})^{d^2} =(\sqrt[d^2]{x^d} + \sqrt[d^2]{y^d})^{d^2} = x^d \oplus_{d^2} y^d $.  So it's an isomorphism into $(\Bbb{R}, \oplus_{d^2}, \cdot)$.  Didn't see that. :D

Comment: ...and the question is...??

Comment: I don't think $F$ is a field. Can you *prove* it?

Comment: OK, it's a field. And so? Since it's isomorphic to the reals you can't say too much about it that you can't say about the reals. What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is merely relabel the elements of $\mathbf R$ by using the fact that $x \mapsto x^d$ is a bijection of $\mathbf R$ with itself when $d$ is odd. This cannot lead to new information (such as new solutions to equations). Your mistakes begin when you say "use the inverse isomorphism"; you should be getting the same old equation that you started with back, not the apparently new equation.

Comment: Please show me where my error is though.  If you can't show me where, and we can't find one, then is there one?

Comment: I'm not trying to gain new information about $\Bbb{R}$ or the isomorphic field to it, I'm interested in solutions to $x^a + y^b - z^c = 0$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath One source of confusion arises from the fact that you cannot iterate your map $x \mapsto x^d$ in the naive sense, because although it goes from $\mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ at the level of sets, these two copies of $\mathbf R$ do not have the same field structure. Despite appearances, the map $x \mapsto x^d$ does *not* have the same domain and codomain, so you cannot iterate it (which is what you appear to do).

Comment: No, I iterate $\phi : F \to F, x \mapsto x^d$ and you can prove that it's a bijection and a homom.

Comment: @EnjoysMath No, it is not. $\mathbf R$ does not have any nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: It's not automorphism of $R$, it's an automorphism of $F$!!!  Cute dog pic btw :D

Comment: @EnjoysMath You have shown that $\mathbf R$ and $F$ are isomorphic (and you are right about that). But isomorphic objects have isomorphic automorphism groups. If $F$ had a nontrivial automorphism, then so would $\mathbf R$. It doesn't.

Comment: @EnjoysMath But you go ahead and try to prove that $\phi$ is an automorphism. You'll see for yourself why it doesn't work. Good night (and nice cat!),